# How do I write a code in Hue SQL for slope or decay rate?

Tags: hue

I have the next table t1 with the next values:

[table t1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cZGM.png)

What I am looking for is to generate a slope(or decay rate) by id, for reading_pct on every other 10 days (from the 1st day to the last day).

I was thinking I can use this code for slope:

```
SELECT sum((x - x_bar) * (y - y_bar)) / sum((x - x_bar) * (x - x_bar)) as slope
FROM
  (SELECT datediff(to_date(reading_dt), id_dt) AS x,
          avg(datediff(to_date(reading dt), id_dt)) over() AS x_bar,
          reading_pct AS y,
          avg(reading_pct) over() AS y_bar
   FROM t1;
```

But I cannot get it to work for every other 10 days on reading_dt, for the same id,  and I cannot get it to work as a subsequent query in a query (either as having or ...where...)
I really need help here.